# Sort a list by Days of the week

Tags: javascript, sorting, html-lists

I have created a list of items that contains information such as a taskname (i.e. take out the garbage), who must do the task, and what day of the week the task needs to be done by. All this information is gathered through text inputs in the html, then displayed as a list item using JavaScript.

Im wondering if there is a simple way to sort my list by the day of the week the task needs to be done. I was thinking perhaps i should add numerical value of 1-7 to strings containing days of the week. (for instance one that contains monday would have a value of 1, ones that have sunday have a value of 7). Then i could sort these numerically.

If anyone could show me how to do this with JavaScript (not jQuery), or an easier way, that would be greatly appreciated. (The more comments in the code the better).

Thanks

```
//links html elements to corresponding javascript variable names

var allTasks = document.getElementById('allTasks');
var taskInput = document.getElementById('taskInput');
var personInput = document.getElementById('personInput');
var dayInput = document.getElementById('dayInput');
var addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
var sortBtn = document.getElementById('sortBtn');


//Create Task List based on input put in text fields
var TaskObject = function(taskText, personText, dayText){
    var self = this;
    self.name="taskName";
    self.listItem;
    self.init = function(){

        //create html elements
        self.listItem = document.createElement("li");

        //create text box and have it display information from the previous inputed task
        var text = document.createElement("text");
        text.innerText = taskText + " ";

        //create text box and have it display information from the previous inputed person
        var text2 = document.createElement("text");
        text2.innerText = personText + " ";

        //create text box and have it display information from the previous inputed day of the week
        var text3 = document.createElement("text");
        text3.innerText = dayText + " ";

        //create delete button and functionality
        var deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
        deleteBtn.innerHTML = "delete";
        deleteBtn.onclick = self.deleteMe;

        // combine html elements
        self.listItem.appendChild(text);
        self.listItem.appendChild(text2);
        self.listItem.appendChild(text3);
        self.listItem.appendChild(deleteBtn);
        allTasks.appendChild (self.listItem);
    }
    self.deleteMe = function(){
        var parent = self.listItem.parentNode;
        parent.removeChild(self.listItem);
    }
}

addBtn.onclick = function (){

    var newTask = new TaskObject(taskInput.value, personInput.value, dayInput.value)

    newTask.init();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an `in-built` `javascript` function that helps in getting the `day of the week`.

```
//Calling the date function
var date = new Date();
//Getting the day of the week
var day_of_week = date.getDay();
```

`date.getDay()` returns a value from `0` to `6` for `sunday` to `saturday` respectively

```
//A function to get the day of the week
function dayOfTheWeek()
{
    var date = new Date();
    var day_of_week = date.getDay();
    switch (day_of_week)
    {
    case 0: return "sunday"
    case 1: return "monday"
    case 2: return "tuesday"
    case 3: return "wednessday"
    case 4: return "thursday"
    case 5: return "friday"
    default: return "saturday"
    }
}
//Calling the function
var day_of_week_in_string = dayOfTheWeek();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(javascript) 
//define your task objects as an array (outside of TaskObject)
  var tasks = [];

 //retrieve a number rather than a text value
 var dayInput = document.getElementById('dayInput').selectedIndex

var newTask = ...
//add this task object to the Task array
tasks.push(newTask)

//now you can sort the array:
tasks.sort(function(a, b){return a.dayInput-b.dayInput});

 (html)
 <select id="dayInput">
 <option value="0">Monday</option>
 <option value="1">Tuesday</option>
 <option value="2">Wednesday</option>
 <option value="3">Thursday</option>
 <!-- etc..  -->
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to your problem. When a new `li` is created, you store a hidden attribute called "data-day-text" and attach it to the `li`. When you sort, you remove the `ul` from the DOM (for performance gains), sort the `li`s according to the `data-day-text`, then re-attach the `li`s and the `ul`.

http://jsfiddle.net/g3et9abh/3/

html:

```
<div id="allTasksContainer">
    <ul id="allTasks"></ul>
</div>
<p>task:
    <input type="text" id="taskInput" />
</p>
<p>person:
    <input type="text" id="personInput" />
</p>
<p>day:
    <input type="text" id="dayInput" />
</p>
<button id="addBtn">add</button>
<button id="sortBtn">sort</button>
```

javascript:

```
//links html elements to corresponding javascript variable names

var allTasksContainer = document.getElementById('allTasksContainer');
var allTasks = document.getElementById('allTasks');
var taskInput = document.getElementById('taskInput');
var personInput = document.getElementById('personInput');
var dayInput = document.getElementById('dayInput');
var addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
var sortBtn = document.getElementById('sortBtn');


//Create Task List based on input put in text fields
var TaskObject = function (taskText, personText, dayText) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = "taskName";
    self.listItem;
    self.init = function () {

        //create html elements
        self.listItem = document.createElement("li");
        self.listItem.dataset.dayText = dayText;

        //create text box and have it display information from the previous inputed task
        var text = document.createElement("text");
        text.innerText = taskText + ' ' + personText + ' ' + dayText;

        //create delete button and functionality
        var deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
        deleteBtn.innerHTML = "delete";
        deleteBtn.onclick = self.deleteMe;

        // combine html elements
        self.listItem.appendChild(text);
        self.listItem.appendChild(deleteBtn);
        allTasks.appendChild(self.listItem);
    }
    self.deleteMe = function () {
        var parent = self.listItem.parentNode;
        parent.removeChild(self.listItem);
    }
}

addBtn.onclick = function () {
    var newTask = new TaskObject(taskInput.value, personInput.value, dayInput.value)
    newTask.init();
}

sortBtn.onclick = function () {
    allTasksContainer.removeChild(allTasks);
    var nodes = [].slice.call(allTasks.getElementsByTagName('li'), 0);
    [].sort.call(nodes, function (a, b) {
        return b.dataset.dayText < a.dataset.dayText ? 1 : b.dataset.dayText > a.dataset.dayText ? -1 : 0;
    });
    while (allTasks.firstChild) {
        allTasks.removeChild(allTasks.firstChild);
    }
    nodes.forEach(function (node) {
        allTasks.appendChild(node);
    });
    allTasksContainer.appendChild(allTasks);
}
```